# Orchestration in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, orchestration

I have started to use jQuery promises to orchestrate asynchronous function execution. Is something like this considered "Clean", or is this silly? Really curious what you all think.

Consider these are all ajax requests.

```
fetchFruit().done( function(result) { 
   if (result == "apple" ) {
     eatFruit().done( function() {
        logTransaction("Ate Fruit").done( function() {
       }) 
    })
   }
})
```

Is this silly? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's just silly, if the functions are synchronous you could just place them one after the other and the one-threaded nature of javascript would ensure they complete before the next one starts. This is uneccessary overhead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I miss communicated. These are asynchronous calls to ajax methods - that I want to control the execution plan for.

Comment: On the other hand, you say it's synchronous, then you say they are ajax requests, which is it? If they are ***asynchronous*** requests, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JasonWells `result is "apple"` should be `result in "apple"` (Line 2)

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks, yea that was a mistake on my part. What if we want to halt the execution starting at fetchFruit if the result of a method call is true. Let's say "checkFruitInventory()"